# Alert Dialog dismiss not happing

Tags: android

i am using the following code. But the alert dialog dismiss is not happening. I am using custom view which has a list view, i am trying on list item click, alert dialog should be dismiss. On item click listener is working but alert dialog is not dismissing. Can any body help me out.

```
View titleView = new View(MixContainerInfoActivity.this);
    titleView = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_unit_title, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView)titleView.findViewById(R.id.custom_title_txt_view);     
    tv.setTypeface(typeFace);
    tv.setText("CONTAINER OR IMPLEMENT...");

    View view = new View(MixContainerInfoActivity.this);
    view = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.unit_list, null);
    containerList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.unit_list_view);
    ArrayAdapter<Vector> containerAdapter = new UnitMenuAdapter(MixContainerInfoActivity.this, R.layout.custom_unit_list, containerVector);     
    containerList.setAdapter(containerAdapter);


     final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MixContainerInfoActivity.this);

     builder.setCustomTitle(titleView);
     builder.setView(view);



     final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
     alert.show(); //edited here

     containerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                System.out.println("Item Clicked..");

                alert.dismiss();

            }
        });
```

Comment: you want to dismiss alertDialog on click of an AdapterView...? how is that possible..? how can they be in foreground at same time..?

Comment: then how can i do the same? is there any clue?

Comment: Thats not possible.... you need to dismiss it when a button in the dialog is clicked... you cannot have both of them  in forground at the same time...

Comment: @all - I think he is using custom list inside the dialog.. So its possible..

Comment: but the same thing is working for Dialog. I mean when i am using Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context).

Comment: see http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-alertdialog-your-android-application to know how to create dialog and set button..

Comment: @user370305 can u please give some clue how it will be possible..many thanks

Comment: Just rearrange the instruction. It will work

Comment: @user370305 what do u mean by that?

Comment: Look at my answer, try it and let me know what happen..

Comment: your mistake is in showing dialog through builder `builder.show();`
     final AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); call alert.show(); instead of builder.show();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and let me know what happen,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MixContainerInfoActivity.this);
View view = new View(MixContainerInfoActivity.this);
view = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.unit_list, null);
builder.setCustomTitle(titleView);
builder.setView(view);
containerList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.unit_list_view);
ArrayAdapter<Vector> containerAdapter = new UnitMenuAdapter(MixContainerInfoActivity.this, R.layout.custom_unit_list, containerVector);     
containerList.setAdapter(containerAdapter);
final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();

containerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                System.out.println("Item Clicked..");
                alert.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Its alert.show() instead of builder.show() and I put final AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); before alert.show();

Comment: alert.show() and alert.dismiss() is working perfectly. Thanks for your gr8 help :)

Answer (score 0):

**setOnItemClickListener** is raised when an item from list is clicked. Since dialog is shown above list, you are not able to click list's item. Instead you should add the following line to your builder and remove *setOnItemClickListener*:

```
//it will dismiss the dialog automatically
builder.setNegativeButton("OK", null);
```